# RecyclerView ViewHolder with programmatically added views in LinearLayout gives error "You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` being used in a `RecyclerView`. In this viewholder, I have a `LinearLayout` which I am programmatically adding views to, the container.

When I run it I get this error:

```
02-09 19:15:57.532 23106-23106/com.fusionprojects.edmodo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:main

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3339)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)
at com.edmodo.stream.PostAttachmentsViewHolder.showFileAttachments(PostAttachmentsViewHolder.java:117)
at com.edmodo.stream.PostAttachmentsViewHolder.setAttachments(PostAttachmentsViewHolder.java:75)
at com.edmodo.stream.StreamPostViewHolder.setPost(StreamPostViewHolder.java:47)
at com.edmodo.postsstream.PostStreamAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PostStreamAdapter.java:49)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4138)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3448)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:543)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)                       
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.
```

I have tried calling `removeAllViews()` and looping through the `LinearLayout`'s children and removing each other individually, but I still get the same error.

How can I handle this and properly remove all the views in the LinearLayout container?

Comment: Can you post your layout XML? Looks like you have a FrameLayout somewhere in it.

Comment: Post the code where you're instantiating the view and adding it to your layout

Comment: Facing the same problem, have you arrived at a solution? Please do tell if you did. You haven't marked any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The child that's being added to the `LinearLayout` has a parent.
Try the following before you add the new view.

```
View view = ... // The View you're adding to the LinearLayout
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
if (parent != null) {
    parent.removeView(view);
}
// Proceed to add the view on your LinearLayout.
```

Although there might be an underlying problem, this can be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Call linearLayout.removeAllViews() in your ViewHolder class when you are binding your object.